# What are the implications of running a query against a MySQL database via Hibernate without starting a transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, guice-persist

It seems to me that we have some code that is not starting a transaction yet for read-only operations our queries via JPA/Hibernate as well as straight SQL seem to work.  A hibernate/jpa session would have been opened by our framework but for a few spots in legacy code we found no transactions were being opened.

What seems to end up happening is that the code usually runs as long as it does not use EntityManager.persist and EntityManager.merge.  However once in awhile (maybe 1/10) times the servlet container fails with this error...

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 314,024,057 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 314,024,057 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.)
```

As far as I can tell only the few spots in our application code that do not have transactions started before a query is made will have this problem.  Does anybody else think it could be the non-transactional query running that causes this behaviour?

FYI here is our stack...

-Guice
-Guice-Persist
-Guice-Servlet
-MySql 5.1.63
-Hibernate/C3P0 4.1.4.Final
-Jetty

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think.

If you start a query without opening a transaction, this transaction will be opened automatically by the underlying layer. This connection, with an opened transaction, will be returned to the connection pool and given to another user, that will receive a connection to an already-opened transaction, and that could lead to inconsistent state.

Here in my company we had a lot of problems in the past with read-only non-transactional queries, and adjusted our framework to handle this.
Besides that, we talked to BoneCP developers and they accepted to develop a set of features to help handle this problem, like auto-rollback uncommitted transactions returned to the pool, and print a stack trace of what method forgot to commit the transaction.

This matter was discussed here:
http://jolbox.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=98